# Spring cloud stream Special Chars in Message received from kinesis

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-integration-aws

When I consume the message from kinesis stream. I get some junk chars with headers etc

```
    @StreamListener(Processor.INPUT)
    public void receive(String message) {       
        System.out.println("Message recieved: "+message);
        throw new RuntimeException("Exception thrown");
    }

    @StreamListener("errorChannel")
    public void transform(ErrorMessage errorMessage) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {      

        //original paylaod 
        System.out.println("Error Oiginal Message Payload"+new String((byte[])errorMessage.getOriginalMessage().getPayload(), "UTF-8"));
        System.out.println("Error Original Message Stream channel"+errorMessage.getOriginalMessage().getHeaders().get("aws_receivedStream"));
    }
```

Aplication yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        input: 
          group: abcd
          destination: stream
          content-type: application/json
          errorChannelEnabled: true
          consumer:
            headerMode: raw
```

I get output at the both the listener and errorChannel with junk characters

I am trying to extract the original message in errorChannel . Is this the right way to convert the bytes message?

```
Message recieved: ?contentType "application/json"{"aa":"cc"}
```

Comment: You need `headerMode: raw` on the producer side too; or `headerMode: embedded` on the consumer side so that the headers are stripped off.

Comment: @GaryRussel Thank you. I think default header mode at consumer side is embedded. I tried with that as well.

Comment: @GaryRussell. In stream listener, I get  correct message. But in ErrorChannel, I get the message with content type and special chars.I am doing like this new String((byte[])errorMessage.getOriginalMessage().getPayload(), "UTF-8") Can you help.

Comment: In that case, you need to use `MessageHeaderUtils.extractHeaders()` on the `originalMessage`.

Comment: See my answer. I wonder if we should do embedded headers extraction *before* sending downstream at all, on the Binder level. To achieve the way when `originalMessage` on the `errorChannel` is transformed already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AWS Kinesis doesn't provide any headers entity. So, to leverage such a functionality in Spring Cloud Stream, we are *embedding* headers into the body of the Kinesis record. For this purpose the `headerMode` is `embeddedHeaders` by default in the Kinesis Binder. And for symmetry between producer and consumer this option must not be changed.

The Framework provides out-of-the-box `EmbeddedHeadersChannelInterceptor` for the target `@StreamListener` channels and embedded headers are extracted and populated properly to the message to send.

When we handle errors in the `errorChannel`, we indeed have an `errorMessage.getOriginalMessage()` as non-transformed - original. And therefore the `payload` of that message is a `byte[]` from the record body containing embedded headers.

If you would like to parse them properly. you should use utility:

```
EmbeddedHeaderUtils.extractHeaders((Message<byte[]>) message, true);
```

Comment: @artem-bilan Is there a way to add headers to body using spring integration? I mean if I manually add a header map in body of my event to kinesis, then using `EmbeddedHeaderUtils.extractHeaders` would still extract the headers?

Comment: Please, raise a new question with more details. SO is not a chat.